# Elastic Search error - variable [relevancy] is not defined

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to query my products ElasticSearch index and create a `script_score` but I keep receiving the error `Variable [relevancy] is not defined.`

I tried replacing the script with just a number, then with Math.log(_score) to make sure the script_score was working properly and the math function is ok, and both queries executed as expected. I also tried `doc['relevancy'].value` and received the same error.

My query is:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/products/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query":    "KQ", 
          "fields": [ "item_id", "extended_desc", "mfg_part_no" ] 
        }
      },
      "script_score" : {
          "script": "Math.log(_score) + Math.log(doc['relevancy'])"
      },
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
'
```

And the mapping for this index is:

```
{
  "products" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "@version" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "extended_desc" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "frecno" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "item_id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "my_analyzer"
        },
        "mfg_part_no" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "relevancy" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replaced  `'` with `\u0027` because this is curl.

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/products/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query":    "KQ", 
          "fields": [ "item_id", "extended_desc", "mfg_part_no" ] 
        }
      },
      "script_score" : {
          "script": "Math.log(_score) + Math.log(doc[\u0027relevancy\u0027].value)"
      },
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
'
```